# What do the numbers in rsync's output mean?

Tags: rsync

When I run `rsync` with the `--progress` flag, I get information about the transfers as follows.

```
path/to/file
          16 100%    0.01kB/s    0:00:01 (xfer#10857, to-check=427700/441502)
```

What do the numbers in the second row mean? I know what some of them are, but what do the others mean (marked with ??? below)?

> 16 ???
>
> 100% amount of transfer completed in this file
>
> 0.0.1kB/s speed of current file transfer
>
> 0:00:01: time elapsed in current file transfer
>
> 10857 count of files transferred
>
> 427700 ???
>
> 441502 ???

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> When the file transfer finishes, rsync
>   replaces the progress line with a
>   summary line that looks like this:
>
> ```
>  1238099 100%  146.38kB/s    0:00:08  (xfer#5, to-check=169/396)
> ```
>
> In this example, the file was 1238099
>   bytes long in total, the average rate
>   of transfer for the whole file was
>   146.38 kilobytes per second over the 8 seconds that it took to complete, it
>   was the 5th transfer of a regular file
>   during the current rsync session, and
>   there are 169 more files for the
>   receiver to check (to see if they are
>   up-to-date or not) remaining out of
>   the 396 total files in the file-list.

from http://samba.anu.edu.au/ftp/rsync/rsync.html under --progress switch

Answer (score 15):

path/to/file
          16 100%    0.01kB/s    0:00:01 (xfer#10857, to-check=427700/441502)

The 16 is the bytes-in-this-file transferred sofar. The 100% lists the percentage of the file transferred: 100% in this case. For very short files the kb/sec number often comes out a bit weird: Small measuring errors cause big differences in the calculated overall speed. Then there is the total time. Then, the transfer number. In the example given, of the 427700 files checked so far, only 10857 needed to be transferred. Based on the modification times rsync decided that no transfer was needed for some of the others. Next there is the number of files left-to-check and the total. Modern rsync implementations will create the list that counts towards the "total" on the fly: only adding to the list if the unchecked number drops below 1000.

Comment: "only adding to the list if the unchecked number drops below 1000" Why do they do that?

Comment: Are the kilos 1000 based or 1024 based?

Comment: In a computer different things can be going on at once. So the CPU might be calculating while the harddrive is moving to a new position in another file. To make things efficient, you want to overlap those different things as much as possible. Worst case, you calculate (using the CPU, leaving the harddrive doing nothing) and then you need that other file so the CPU ends up doing nothing while the harddrive goes to the new position. Rsync balances CPU, harddrive, network transfers. To that end the task of gathering the list tries to kept 1000 files ahead of the check and transfer task.